# Null validation in extracted method

Tags: c#, .net-core, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I use c# 8 and nullable analyzers in `.csproj`

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  <RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>true</RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>
  <RunAnalyzersDuringLiveAnalysis>true</RunAnalyzersDuringLiveAnalysis>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Below code which validates request via extracted method, shows such warning:

[image]

```
class Program
{
    public void Foo(Data request)
    {
        Validate(request);

        request.Properties.TryGetValue("bar", out var bar);
    }

    private static void Validate(Data request)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request));
        }

        if (request.Properties == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Data.Properties));
        }
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public Dictionary<string, string>? Properties { get; set; }
}
```

If I put validation code directly into method (like below) there is no warning.

**Why is that?**

**How can I have Validation extracted and don't have warning?**

```
class Program
{
    public void Foo(Data request)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request));
        }

        if (request.Properties == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Data.Properties));
        }

        request.Properties.TryGetValue("bar", out var bar);
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public Dictionary<string, string>? Properties { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that currenty (if you want to keep validation of both `request` and `request.Properties` in the method `Validation`) the only way to fix this problem is to use `null forgiving operator`:

```
request.Properties!.TryGetValue("bar", out var bar);
```

---

If you consider extracting validation of the `request.Properties` from the method `Validation` then you can use attribute [`NotNullAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullattribute?view=netcore-3.1) to fix the problem. Attribute `NotNullAttribute` specifies that an input argument was not `null` when the call returns. Using this attribute we can declare `Validate` the next way:

```
private static void Validate([System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.NotNull] object? obj, string name)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
    }
}
```

After calling this method `Validate` code analyzer know that the `obj` is not null, and it will not produce warnings for code that access `obj`.

Then we can use `Validate` without getting warnings:

```
public static void Foo(Data request)
{
    Validate(request, nameof(request));
    Validate(request.Properties, nameof(request.Properties));

    request.Properties.TryGetValue("bar", out var bar);
}
```