# In C# indicate to static analyzers that a method guarantees non-null values

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, static-code-analysis

With .NET 6, it is easy to create helper or extension methods that can throw an exception without dirtying up the stack trace.  For example:

```
    [System.Diagnostics.StackTraceHidden]
    public static void ThrowIfNullOrWhitespace(this string? stringValue, Exception exception)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue))
            throw exception;
    }
```

In this case, you can call that method

```
foo.ThrowIfNullOrWhitespace(new ArgumentException("null or whitespace"));
```

but subsequent uses of `foo` in the code still get "possible null value" squiggles in the editor.

I also see this issue in more mundane cases where methods like `foo = DoSomething(foo)` guarantee a non-null result internally.

Is there an attribute or some other way to tell the C# static code analyzers that these kinds of methods enforce postconditions that guarantee that `foo` is not null?

Comment: Native C++ does this too in VS 2019, mixing in too many false positives with the occasional valid case.

Comment: You can apply [`[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.NotNull]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullattribute?view=net-6.0) to `this string? stringValue` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62569413) by [Iliar Turdushev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12833205/iliar-turdushev) to [Null validation in extracted method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62559897).   This attribute *Specifies that an input argument was not null when the call returns.*

Comment: @DaveS, that only means that you're using it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute you're looking for is `[NotNull]`, used like this:

```
public static void ThrowIfNullOrWhitespace([NotNull]this string? stringValue, Exception exception)
```

You can see literally the same example in the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis#postconditions-maybenull-and-notnull).

And you can see your function implemented in the Windows Community Toolkit [here](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/rel/7.1.0/Microsoft.Toolkit.Diagnostics/Guard.cs#L65).